# Headless unittest and GUI items

Tags: python

I am trying to create unit tests for my Blender add-on. When there are no GUI elements involved the approach found here works fine: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Tests/Python

E.g., running `my_test.py` in Blender headless:

```
blender --background -noaudio --python tests/my_test.py  -- --verbose
```

However, functions requiring certain GUI elements such as the position of the mouse cursor fail. For instance, I want to test a function that calls `view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(.)`. I cannot run this even when I omit the `--background` argument. I guess the context is not fully created at the time when the test is executed.

Can we somehow tell Blender in headless to simulate a viewport, mouse etc? That would be very neat as I then could run the tests in a CI/CD chain.

Comment: When headless the properties that pertain to the UI are `None`.  eg `context.area, context.region`  Perhaps look into `--enable-event-simulate` start-up option.

Comment: That can come in handy! Seems that it can simulate input events: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html

Comment: I tried to do this prior to running my function `bpy.context.window.event_simulate("MOUSEMOVE", "NOTHING")`, however I get segfault. Maybe the simulation feature is not fully developed.